# Vba При копировании файлов из ZIP Нужно не копировать файлы расширения SIG

Tags: vba

В zip файле есть файлы Расширения SIG и их копировать не нужно но как это сделать не понимаю

```
Sub Unzip()
    Dim FSO As Object
    Dim oApp As Object
    Dim Fname
    Dim FileNameFolder As Variant
    Dim DefPath As String
    Dim x As Integer
 
    Fname = Application.GetOpenFilename(filefilter:="Zip Files (*.zip), *.zip", _
                                        MultiSelect:=True)
    If TypeName(Fname) = "Boolean" Then
        MsgBox "Вы ничего не выбрали!"
        Exit Sub
    End If
        
        DefPath = "C:\Users\Ass\Downloads\TEST"
        If Right(DefPath, 1) <> "\" Then
            DefPath = DefPath & "\"
        End If
        x = 1
        While x <= UBound(Fname)
        FileNameFolder = DefPath
         
        
        Set oApp = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
        oApp.Namespace(FileNameFolder).CopyHere oApp.Namespace(Fname(x)).Items
        
        x = x + 1
        Wend
  
        
        MsgBox "You find the files here: " & FileNameFolder
                 
        On Error Resume Next
        Set FSO = CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject")
        FSO.deletefolder Environ("Temp") & "\Temporary Directory*", True
     
End Sub
```

Comment: `Fname` - массив имён файлов. Что мешает сначала повыбрасывать из него все ненужные имена, и только потом копировать?

Comment: @Akina Да, но хранит он имя файла ZIP.
Внутри ZIP файла, .xlsx и .sig файлы. И я не знаю как именно выбросить фалы расширения sig из копирования.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Спасибо всем, нашел все таки способ копировать определенные файлы
Вместо этих строчек

```
        Set oApp = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
        oApp.Namespace(FileNameFolder).CopyHere oApp.Namespace(Fname(x)).Items
```

(копирование всех файлов архива)

Нужно использовать

```
        With CreateObject("Shell.Application").Namespace((DefPath))
        .CopyHere Fname(x) & "\" & "0.xlsx"
        End With
        x = x + 1
        Wend
```

Где  0.xlsx - имя файлов для копирования